# What map component is used in AirNav Live Flight tracker?

Tags: dictionary, c++builder, c++builder-2010

I'd like to use map in my c++ builder application but don't know what map component to use!!
It should be INTERNET independent(rather than Google Map), that works offline!
Recently downloaded AirNav Live Flight tracker, it has a very good map component !!!
I liked it very much. Hope to find such kind of map component.
Does anyone know what component it is ????
Very need it !!!! 
Tell me please asap! 
here is the screenshot of a AirNav Live Flight Tracker
http://www.flickr.com/photos/67246820@N08/6115423800/in/photostream

Comment: You can use online tool to check live flight tracker
https://www.workversatile.com/live-flight-tracker

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no map component in the native VCL, so you will have to either make a custom map control, or find a third-party map control.  You can use WinSpector or Spy++ or other similar utility to find out the class name of the map control that AirNav uses, and then go from there.

Comment: Thanks Remy! I did what you said! The class is TGlobe, found out that it's used TGlobe GIS and Mapping component in this app. Tried to download it but unfortunately it's not available for c++ builder 2010m , only for CB5 !